# How do I get all n! combinations of possible lists that can be created from numbers 1 to n?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-itertools, iterable

It's kind of difficult to explain, so let me give an example:

For `n=3`,
I want to make all lists:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

How do I implement a function that each time returns the next list? (or one that returns a list of all possible lists?)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: here is a recursive implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116911/all-permutations-of-a-string-in-python-recursive/34620370#34620370

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are the permutations of `range(1, n + 1)`:

```py
from itertools import permutations

n = 3
for permutation in permutations(range(1, n + 1)):
  print(permutation)
```

`range(1, n + 1)` gives you the interval `[1, n]`, as `range` creates half open intervals. `itertools.permutations` takes all those values and gives you all possible combinations.

If you have the memory for it (`n!` gets big pretty fast), you can collect them all into a list:

```py
output = list(permutations(range(1, n + 1)))
```